# SQL Server Replication - Two Identical Publications

Tags: sql-server, replication

For SQL Server Replication, our DBA setup two identical publications with one subscriber to each (identical replicated databases).

The rational is to allow independent maintenance on each of the subscribers.

Is this normal? Reasonable?

Comment: My first reaction is "that sounds weird", but I've been surprised by things like this before. I'd want to hear more about the rationale. Specifically, what maintenance operations are possible with the current setup that aren't possible with one publication and two subscribers to that? Said another way, right now you're paying the cost of maintaining two publications. What benefit are you getting for it?

Comment: Maybe I should explain our our procedure.  
When we go to production and have subscription changes, we
1) Use F5 BIGIP to route traffic to the "online" reporting server (A)
2) Update offline server (B)
3) Route traffic to B
4) Update A
5) Route traffic to A & B